# Execute command for editor scroll in VSCode

Tags: scroll, visual-studio-code, command

That should work:

```
const vscode = require('vscode')

async function commentLine() {
  const success = await vscode.commands
  .executeCommand('vscode.editorScroll', {
    to:'down',
    by: 'halfPage',
    revealCursor: true,
  });
  console.log(success)
}
```

but upon running this code after a user action, I receive 'vscode.revealCursor` is unknown command in a warning modal.

Any idea why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual error message is:

```
command 'vscode.editorScroll' not found
```

The problem is not `revealCursor`, the problem is the `vscode.` prefix on the command name.  Change the `executeCommand` first argument to just `"editorScroll"` and it works.

Also this particular command does not return anything, so `success` is `undefined`.